# how to support apk on maximum android devices

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, apk

I have uploaded my application's apk on google play. It supports only about 5000 devices out of the 7000 present. Arround 2000 devices are not supported by my application.

My manifest permissions are below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Can anyone tell me the exact problem and how I could build an apk that will support all of these devices?

Comment: For supporting all the android device..Android minSdkVersion and maxSdkVersion are responsible also mention supports-screens in menifest file.

Comment: <uses-sdk
 android:minSdkVersion="8"/> add these lines to ur manifest.

Comment: You need to provide more information than you have. Are you using any features that are specific to API 11+ or API 14+? In which case you **WILL** not be able to support all the devices. Depending on the possibilities you *may* have to consider using the various support libraries available. As always read through the Android Developer website. Everything you need is right there.